# calculate Age from year, month and day fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table of people and I need to know how many of them are actual minors.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) as minors from 
FilesMain a INNER JOIN Sides b
ON a.FileID = b.FileID 
INNER JOIN SideData c 
ON b.SideDataID = c.SideDataID
WHERE a.StatusCode IN (100,101) AND (YEAR(CURDATE()) - BirthYear<17)
```

Basically in the query above, I am calculating current date year minus BirthYear field.

I have the persons birth date separated to **year**, **month** and **day** in 3 different fields. please don't ask why. I inherited the data. What would be the correct way to use the Month and Day fields as well to get a more specific result. Just using Year will treats someone born January first and December 31 the same.

Thanks

Comment: "please don't ask why" It's your data now. Just fix your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 
                      CONCAT_WS('-', BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay), 
                      CURRENT_DATE) < 17
```

Also you may add generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD COLUMN DOB DATE 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT_WS('-', BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay));
```

and use this column instead of the above expression.